# Parameterize DDL SQL Snowflake

Tags: sql, variables, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In the below code is there any way I can parameterize the sst part.

I tried with concat and other methods like `set ssourl=url, sst = $ssour`l but of no luck. And many other methods like using concat, Identifier.

I can't parameterize cert since it has limit of 256 bytes. Is there any way I can parameterize sst in the below code. Thanks

```
alter account set saml_identity_provider = '{
  "cert": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "sst": "https://corp.com/app/<app_id>/sso/saml",
  "type"  : "test"
  "label" : "singlesignOn"
  }';
```

Comment: It should be possible to “write” the command via a javascript stored proceedure, thus use any javascript base text construction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be done with Snowflake Scripting block:

```
DECLARE
  CERT STRING DEFAULT 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
  SST  STRING DEFAULT 'https://corp.com/app/<app_id>/sso/saml';
  TYPE STRING DEFAULT 'test';
  
  
  SQL STRING DEFAULT $$alter account set saml_identity_provider = '{
  "cert": "<cert>",
  "sst": "<sst>",
  "type"  : "<test>"
  "label" : "singlesignOn"
  }'$$;
BEGIN
   SQL := REPLACE(:SQL, '<cert>', :CERT);
   SQL := REPLACE(:SQL, '<sst>',  :SST);
   SQL := REPLACE(:SQL, '<type>', :TYPE);
       
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :SQL;
   RETURN :SQL;
END;
```

Output:

[image]

EDIT:

**[Using Snowflake Scripting in SnowSQL and the Classic Web Interface](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/running-examples.html#introduction)**

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $$

DECLARE
  CERT STRING DEFAULT 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
  SST  STRING DEFAULT 'https://corp.com/app/<app_id>/sso/saml';
  TYPE STRING DEFAULT 'test';
  
  
  SQL STRING DEFAULT 'alter account set saml_identity_provider =' || CHAR(39) || '{"cert": "<cert>",  "sst": "<sst>","type"  : "<test>"  "label" : "singlesignOn"}' || CHAR(39);
BEGIN
   SQL := REPLACE(:SQL, '<cert>', :CERT);
   SQL := REPLACE(:SQL, '<sst>',  :SST);
   SQL := REPLACE(:SQL, '<type>', :TYPE);
       
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :SQL;
   RETURN :SQL;
END;
$$;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But while I am trying above command, I am getting below errors.001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 2 at position 300 unexpected '<EOF>'.
001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 1 at position 0 unexpected 'SST'.
001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 1 at position 0 unexpected 'SQL'.
001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 2 at position 48 unexpected '<EOF>'.
001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 1 at position 0 unexpected 'SQL'.
001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:

Comment: Is there any way to fix it. Thanks

Comment: @Karikaaalan Are you calling it from Classing Web UI or Snowsight? It should be invoked from modern UI: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-snowsight-gs.html

Comment: I am using snowsql. Trying from terminal. Is there any way I can invoke using snowsql

Comment: @Karikaaalan Please find [Using Snowflake Scripting in SnowSQL and the Classic Web Interface](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/running-examples.html#introduction)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I tried this and it is showing unexpected for alter. I tried with and without dollar for alter but facing same issue.

Comment: @Karikaaalan I suggest trying again. I have extended the answer providing a way to run from Classic UI.

Comment: In the above script is there any way I can pass the value of certificate from a file since I can't hard code there @Lukasz szozda

Comment: @Karikaaalan This is a completely new question as regardless of using `SET variable` you will still need to pass the values. I suggest either creating a stored procedure and/or passing variables from [SnowSQL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-use.html#defining-variables-while-connecting-d-or-variable-command-line-flag)